# Is it possible to send SMS to myself via my telegram-bot?

Tags: api, telegram, telegram-bot

In Telegram API documentation i found a method [auth.sendSms](https://core.telegram.org/method/auth.sendSms), but I'm not sure this is exactly what we need. Prompt, how to send to myself SMS via Telegram API? The programming language is not important (perhaps php or ruby). Thank you in advance for any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. It's impossible. Btw, "auth.sendSms" - is not bot API, it's native client API.

Comment: so is there any way to send sms with telegram as a developer?!